# Lightswitch HTML Client, Set Default Value of List Picker

Tags: select, visual-studio-lightswitch, listpicker

Lightswitch renders my navigation property as a list picker, but I can't figure out how to set a default value on it. There must be a simple way to do it. I've scoured the net, and all the suggestions look hopelessly kludgy. Is there a good comprehensive tutorial out there for Lightswitch? The most common tasks like setting the default value on a dropdown are ridiculously hard to figure out.

Comment: Answered this myself, below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

```
myapp.Address.created = function (entity) {

    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.MailListData.CountryRegion_LUs.filter("CountryRegionCode eq 'US'").execute().then(function (result) {
        entity.CountryRegion_LU = result.results[0];
    });
}
```

You want to write a handler for the *created* Javascript event for the parent entity. I'm binding CountryRegion_LUs, which are in the Address entity, so I am binding to the created event of the Address entity, not the CountryRegion_LUs entity. "MailListData" is the name of my database. I'm using an OData query to pull out the CountryRegion_LU that has a CountryRegionCode of "US." I could have simply used "load()" instead of *.filter("CountryRegionCode eq 'US'").execute()* to load all the records, and then picked the member of the result-set I wanted, say results.result[221], but then I'd be bringing all the data over and filtering client-side.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this post of which I asked myself, there is a detailed answer on the problem you have above: it explains how to set your modal picker/details picker with a default value

[Lightswitch HTML Client - set modal picker value when screen created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540559/lightswitch-html-client-set-modal-picker-value-when-screen-created)

any questions feel free to ask