# Lightswitch many to many control

Tags: many-to-many, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a many to many control checkbox list where a user can select items. I was wondering if by default if the list can be selected already when the screen is loaded on the initialize data workspace method screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in regards to this post, this should help you set the default value of a details picker.. (HTML Client)

[Lightswitch HTML Client - set modal picker value when screen created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540559/lightswitch-html-client-set-modal-picker-value-when-screen-created)

but as links can break, heres a summary of how to do it...

1. add the below code to the js file of the screen (change Application data to your data source)

   ```
   function defaultLookup (entity, destinationPropertyName, sourceCollectionName, options) {
   /// <summary>
   /// Defaults an entity's lookup property
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="entity" type="Object">The entity featuring the lookup property to default</param>
   /// <param name="destinationPropertyName" type="String">The lookup property against the entity to default</param>
   /// <param name="sourceCollectionName" type="String">The collection from which to source the lookup value</param>
   /// <param name="options" type="PlainObject" optional="true">
   /// A set of key/value pairs used to select additional configuration options. All options are optional.
   /// <br/>- String filter: If supplied, defines the match condition for the required default, otherwise the lookup defaults to the first entry in the source collection
   /// </param>
   options = options || {}; // Force options to be an object
   var source = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData[sourceCollectionName]; // DataServiceQuery
   var query = {}; //DataServiceQuery
   if (options.filter) {
       query = source.filter(options.filter);
   } else {
       query = source.top(1);
   }
   query.execute().then(function (result) {
       entity[destinationPropertyName] = result.results[0];
   });
   ```

   };
2. set the value based upon the foreign key (this is under the screen created code):

   ```
   var defaultValue = "Goods in"; 
   //screen.ShippingDetails.ShippingName;
   var filter = "(ShippingName eq " + msls._toODataString(defaultValue, ":String") + ")";
   defaultLookup((1)screen.Order, "(2)ShippingDetail", "(3)ShippingDetails", { filter: filter });
   ```

(1) refers to the screen you are currently on

(2) references the name of the table in the left hand panel (ShippingDetail)

(3) references the name of the table in solution explorer (ShippingDetails)

Comment: Sorry I meant the silverlight client