# lightswitch html client set default value for details picker

Tags: html, client, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to set a default value for a details picker in lightswitch html client. I have tried:

var picker = screen.findContentItem("SelectedItemType");
    picker.value = "MONITOR";

I am trying to set it in the created method of the screen.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightswitch HTML Client - set modal picker value when screen created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540559/lightswitch-html-client-set-modal-picker-value-when-screen-created)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. And the created event should work.

Try:

1. screen.Property_MyString = "Default Value";

Worked example:

1. Open your screen.
2. Click 'Add Data Item' -> 'Local Property' -> 'String'
3. Name it something: e.g. 'Property_MyString'
4. Click 'Write Code' -> 'Created'
5. Type: screen.Property_MyString = "Default Value";
6. Add the new Property to your screen.

If you want to set a default of a Details Picker:

```
var filter = "Id eq " + msls._toODataString(YourDefaultValueId, ":Int64");
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.YOURDATASOURCE.YOURDATATABLE.filter(filter).execute().then(function (result) {
    var defaultValue = result.results[0];
    screen.YOURPROPERTY = defaultValue;
});
```

Comment: wat happens when I use display name is that it changes the label of the content item doesnt set a default value.

Comment: Argh, you're right! One sec just grabbed a coffee i'll update the answer.

Comment: still trying to understand it mate

Comment: see adding default values to local string property is ok its just the local properties from the DB. The dropdownlist wont populate with my default value

Comment: hey mate didnt quiet understand it im working on another part now but thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

look at this post asked by myself, this should solve your issue, if you have any questions feel free to ask :)

[Lightswitch HTML Client - set modal picker value when screen created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540559/lightswitch-html-client-set-modal-picker-value-when-screen-created)

but heres what code you should use:

1. paste this on line 2 of your JS document:

   ```
   function defaultLookup(entity, destinationPropertyName, sourceCollectionName, options) {
   /// <summary>
   /// Defaults an entity's lookup property
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="entity" type="Object">The entity featuring the lookup property to default</param>
   /// <param name="destinationPropertyName" type="String">The lookup property against the entity to default</param>
   /// <param name="sourceCollectionName" type="String">The collection from which to source the lookup value</param>
   /// <param name="options" type="PlainObject" optional="true">
   /// A set of key/value pairs used to select additional configuration options. All options are optional.
   /// <br/>- String filter: If supplied, defines the match condition for the required default, otherwise the lookup defaults to the first entry in the source collection
   /// </param>
   options = options || {}; // Force options to be an object
   var source = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ProjectHandlerData[sourceCollectionName]; // DataServiceQuery
   var query = {}; //DataServiceQuery
   if (options.filter) {
   query = source.filter(options.filter);
   } else {
   query = source.top(1);
   }
   query.execute().then(function (result) {
   entity[destinationPropertyName] = result.results[0];
   });
   };
   ```
2. on your screen created event, type in this code (ammend the screen values and table names to match yours:

   myapp.AddEditHolidayRequest.created = function (screen) {

   ```
   var defaultValue = "Monitor";
   var filter = "(ProductName eq " + msls._toODataString(defaultValue, ":String") + ")";
   defaultLookup(screen.Order, "Part", "Parts", { filter: filter });
   ```

   }

ProductName: this is the column name as called in your database table where the name "Monitor" is stored under.

screen.Order is whatever screen your on

the difference between 1."Part" and 2."Parts"

1. if you were to open the table from the solution explorer, under the data source folder, the name displayed on the top here goes in number 1
2. will be the name of your table as shown under the data source in the solution explorer on the right hand side

Comment: myapp.activeDataWorkspace.WMSData.GetItemTypeByName("MONITOR").execute().then(function (response) {
        screen.SelectedItemType = response.results[0];
    });

Comment: I created a query called GetItemTypeByName and had a string parameter